# How to make rectangle not leave canvas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rectangles

So I have created a rectangle on a canvas using javascript like in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZPlNOzLrdw

```
    window.onload = function()
    {

        var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

        canvas.addEventListener('keydown', moveIt, true);

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 30, 30);

        var x = 100;
        var y = 100;


        function moveIt(e) 
    {

        if (e.keyCode == 38)
        {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
            y = y - 10;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30); 
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 40)
        {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        y = y + 10;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        x = x - 10;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 39)
        {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        x = x + 10;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I press the keys to move the rectangle around when it reaches the edge it doesn't stop. How do create a function etc to keep it in the canvas and just stop when it reaches the edge?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: _My code looks the exact same._ - **What** code? Please [edit] your question to provide said code.

Comment: I have added the code, what I meant is that it's in the youtube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need additional if-statements to do a check before moving. You need to make sure `y > 0` before moving the square up, `y < canvas.height - 30` (30 being the height of your square) before moving down, and same for `x` with widths. The code below should work for you:

```
function moveIt(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 38){
        if(y > 0){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
            y = y - 10;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30); 
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40){
        if(y < canvas.height - 30){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            y = y + 10;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37){
        if(x > 0){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            x = x - 10;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 39){
        if(x < canvas.width - 30){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            x = x + 10;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}
```